# vim folding syntax for scss

Tags: vim, syntax, sass

What are your techniques for folding scss code?  It doesn't seam that Mr. Pope has this defined in his syntax file:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-haml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are using the new scss syntax, it is as simple as:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.css,*.scss,*.less setlocal foldmethod=marker foldmarker={,}
```