# Autofolding in HAML files

Tags: haml, vim

I was searching for solutions to autofold few types of files i'm using, mainly `*.rb`, `*.scss`, `*.css`, `*.html` and few other common languages.

However i can't find a solution to auto-fold a `haml` files. I've found those two topics but i'm not quite sure what the vimrc lines in those examples mean.

- [vim folding syntax for scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671046/vim-folding-syntax-for-scss)
- [How do I enable automatic folds in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789605/how-do-i-enable-automatic-folds-in-vim)

Have you any idea how can i achieve that? Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 1):

you can customize it to your liking by manually editing a copy of the syntax file

1. Copy $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/haml.vim into your $HOME/.vim/syntax/ or vimfiles/syntax/  folder to customize its behavior
2. Modify it according to `:help syn-fold`  (basically add the word "fold" at the end of syntax regions you want to fold)
3. Put this in your .vimrc to use foldmethod=syntax when editing haml files

   `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.haml setlocal foldmethod=syntax`